# Android: AlphaAnimation - no duration

Tags: java, android, animation, fadeout, duration

I just want to create a fade out effect on a VideoView object.
The problem: Although I did set a certain duration for the animation, it looks like there's no duration. The VideoView object disappears immediately..

Things I've already tried:

```
AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
anim.setDuration(2000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mVideoView.startAnimation(anim);
```

the second try:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
mVideoView.startAnimation(anim);

in fadeout.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 >
<alpha
  android:fromAlpha="1.0"
  android:toAlpha="0.0"
  android:duration="2000"
  />
</set>
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not entirely sure VideoView supports this kind of animation.
I did a workaround by fading in a black ImageView object...yeah, it's not best solution.
But the effect is the same :D
Another way would be to create a screenshot, deactivate the VideoView and then to let the screenshot fade out.